# Do Greek and Hebrew words have only one meaning in scripture regardless of the context?

Tags: greek, hebrew, hermeneutical-approaches, linguistics

Is it a legitimate linguistic feature within scriptures that the words of scripture only have one meaning each?

For example, the KJV translates Strong's G1242 in the following manner: covenant (20x), testament (13x). Is that an error by the translators based on a principle of "one word, one meaning"? Or can a word be used with differing meanings?

Now I personally think that the word διαθήκη IS used consistently in the scriptures to refer to a "compact" rather than a "disposition of property" so that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking whether each scriptural word, like γίνομαι for example always means ONE of the following:

> The KJV translates Strong's G1096 in the following manner: be (255x), come to pass (82x), be made (69x), be done (63x), come (52x), become (47x), God forbid (with G3361) (15x), arise (13x), have (5x), be fulfilled (3x), be married to (3x), be preferred (3x), not translated (14x), miscellaneous (4x), vr done (2x).

Or is it a matter of opinion/"private interpretation" whether to use context to decide the author's intent or to use etymology and/or a single usage to determine all scriptural usages?

Comment: This has been an open question for at least 70 years and in some senses for millennia. Here's just one recent example of one author's dissection of another author's attempt at an answer and an alternate author's answers: https://koine-greek.com/2018/12/19/against-monosemy-the-complete-series/

Since this site claims to "prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed", you might consider rephrasing the question. Perhaps the only common ground among today's linguistic approaches is: limiting "meaning" to a set of lexical glosses is poor practice.

Comment: I once saw a translation on the internet that followed this approach. The first line began something like "In the beginning fattened God..." I think results like these are reason enough to dismiss this method.

Comment: If you want to see this idea applied, look up the non-translations called "Mechanical Translations". They are truly abhorrent.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87511/discussion-on-question-by-ruminator-do-greek-and-hebrew-words-have-only-one-mean).

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the question about constant (singular) meanings of words, "Yes" under the following conditions:

- All people spoke absolutely and only literally and never used metaphor or simile
- Grammar was very simple and completely consistent with no exceptions
- When translating from source to receiving language, both languages have precisely identically meaning words
- Syntax did not affect semantics

Of course, none of these things are true except for a very small number of words.  Further, words have a range of meanings that are influenced by context, idiom, syntax, metaphor, literary devices (like irony) and many more.  That is the "glory" of human languages.  Checkout any good lexicon or dictionary for the range of meanings a word my convey - for some it is in the dozens!

Despite all this, the Bible meaning is usually very clear, if not locally, at least by considering all the material germane to the subject.

Answer (score 2):

There never is a one-to-one correspondence between the vocabularies of different languages. This is normal. For example, the language of an agricultural nation may have names for animals of specific ages, while these are dropping out of many modern languages in urban areas.

Similarly, there is no one-to-one correspondence between theological terms. Usually, translations pick the term that approaches the original sense of the word, but sometimes translations may have a different goal and try to best represent the original theology behind the text instead of the text itself (leading to a freer translation). No matter how freely you translate, translation is *always* interpretation.

There are some translations which attempt to translate words in the source language always in the same way, thus creating an artificial language which does have a one-to-one correspondence with the source language. The idea is that in such a translation it is easier to see connections between texts. But these translations are never completely faithful to their own philosophy, and are often difficult to read. Readers also still tend to project their concept of the modern word back onto the text. This is less of a problem when the reader learns the source text.

While this question was about vocabulary, similar questions can be asked about syntax. Some translations, like Robert Alter's recently finished one-man translation of the Hebrew Bible, attempt to reflect the Hebrew syntax as much as possible, while others attempt to produce more idiomatic English (or whatever the target language is).